# How does Qt expect me to link QML modules?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

My problem is when I import my custom module in my main.qml file, I get a runtime error saying that the module is not installed. Here is an example:

```
// main.qml

import QtQuick
import Ui

Window {
    visible: true

    MyComponent {
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
}
```

```
// Ui/MyComponent.qml

import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls

Item {
    Button {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: "Click"
    }
}
```

```
// Main.cpp

#include <QtGui/QGuiApplication>
#include <QtQml/QQmlApplicationEngine>

auto main(int argumentCount, char* arguments[]) -> int
{
    QGuiApplication const application(argumentCount, arguments);
    QQmlApplicationEngine const engine("qrc:/main.qml");

    return QGuiApplication::exec();
}
```

```
// CMakeLists.txt

...

find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core Gui Qml)

add_subdirectory(Ui)

qt6_add_executable(Application Main.cpp)
qt6_add_qml_module(Application URI Application QML_FILES main.qml NO_RESOURCE_TARGET_PATH)
target_link_libraries(Application PRIVATE Qt6::Gui Qt6::Qml Ui)
```

```
// Ui/CMakeLists.txt

find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Qml)

qt6_add_qml_module(Ui URI Ui QML_FILES MyComponent.qml)
```

According to Qt documentation, qt_add_qml_module creates two targets: the first one is a backing library and the second one is a plugin. Which one do I have to link to my executable? What about linking to other modules?

I think I tried every possible combination and the only way it works is when I link static plugin, and it's even getting mentioned in very few Qt blogs, but they don't explain why it has to be that way. Actually, no matter how long I research this, no one seems to have an explanation for that. The same story with why I don't have to link any libraries when using standard QtQuick modules.

Comment: I believe at least one problem is that you have to add `import Ui` in your main.qml to load the module.

Comment: For what it's worth, I battled with this forever too. I eventually went the route of linking the static plugins to the app because that was the only way I could get it working. I followed this [example](https://github.com/scytheStudio/qt_add_qml_module_example).

Comment: @JarMan Forgot to add the import statement to my example. The problem is the same though

Comment: @JarMan What about linking modules to modules. Should I link them as static plugins?

Comment: I'm not linking modules to other modules in my app. Although if that was straightforward enough to do, I might like to try it.

Answer (score 2):

For modules you have to add ***plugin*** to the name. So it will be:

```
target_link_libraries(Application PRIVATE Qt6::Gui Qt6::Qml Uiplugin)
```

"plugin" in Lowercase!

Here you can find more details about module creation: [Qt Documentation: Writing QML Modules](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtqml-writing-a-module.html)

Comment: I'm aware of this solution, but I still can't understand why it has to be that way

Comment: It is a naming convention. Hard to tell, why is like this. But it has something to do with the backing plugin class having the URI extended with upper case "Plugin" and the generated plugin itself having the URI extended with lower case "plugin" for differentiation.

Comment: In this link you can read more about auto naming and how to change plugin names, if you want to adapt them: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt-add-qml-module.html#targets-and-plugin-targets

Comment: I wasn't referring to the naming convention, but to why I have to link the plugin specifically, why I can't just link the backing library, since the documentation says that the plugin is needed when the backing library is not linked already. This is so confusing.

Comment: It is not confusing at all thb. The think that make you confusing here is an expectation of them installed already w/o linking them to the target. But it is only for the target's itself not for the libraries(Ui a library here and I'm sure that you have defined add_library(or qt6_add_library) somewhere in Ui/CMakeList.txt file not in the root CMakeFile). Since the add_library command is not linking anything to the target you have to link them to the main target separately(if qt_add_module used plugin suffix required) Otherwise you can not expect the target will know the presence of your library